# VBA Word macro - inserting table rows at end of table creates infinite loop

Tags: vba, ms-word, infinite-loop

I'm writing a set of macros to format a series of tables in a document. Part of this requires inserting a new row at the end of each table - however, when I try to do it using `For Each <table> in ActiveDocument.Tables`, it ends up inserting an infinite number of rows at the bottom of the first table. 
Both of these subs will enter an infinite loop:

```
Sub insertBottomRow1()
    Dim theTable As Table
    Dim theNewRow As Row
    For Each theTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        Set theNewRow = theTable.Rows.Add
        'Other row formatting
    Next theTable
End Sub

Sub insertBottomRow2()
    Dim theTable As Table
    Dim theNewRow As Row
    For Each theTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        theTable.Rows.Last.Select
        Selection.InsertRowsBelow
        Set theNewRow = theTable.Rows.Last
        'Other row formatting
    Next theTable
End Sub
```

I have a similar sub which uses the same structure to insert a row at the top of the tables, and this does not enter an infinite loop.

```
Sub insertTopRow()
    Dim theTable As Table
    Dim theNewRow As Row
    For Each theTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        Set theNewRow = theTable.Rows.Add(theTable.Rows.First)
        'Other row formatting
    Next theTable
End Sub
```

I've done some experimentation (adding counters to the added rows, and stepping through the debugger), and the two subs that crash seem to be re-selecting the first table instead of moving onto the next table.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your for each is going on forever, but you can easily just convert it to a normal for loop if you're having issues like so:

```
Sub insertTopRow()
    Dim theTable As Table
    Dim theNewRow As Row
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 to ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
        Set theTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
        Set theNewRow = theTable.Rows.Add(theTable.Rows.First)
        'Other row formatting
    Next i
End Sub

 Sub insertBottomRow()
    Dim theTable As Table
    Dim theNewRow As Row
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 to ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
        Set theTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
        Set theNewRow = theTable.Rows.Add
        'Other row formatting
    Next i
End Sub
```

You may also want to confirm it is an infinite loop, you can always break your executing code by pressing Ctrl + Pause/Break.

Another tip would be to combine these functions if the 'Other row formatting is the same for the top and bottom rows. You can just create a boolean parameter and have an if/else statement around the 'Set theNewRow =' line.

Comment: Thanks - switching to a counting loop seems to solve the problem. 

I'm still curious (academically) as to the root issue in my original code (maybe something to do with how `Rows.Add` works), but at least I can move forward.

Comment: Maybe each time you call 'Add' internally it creates a new table. Academically you can just set a breakpoint inside your old code, then keep looking at ActiveDocument.Tables.Count, to see if it increases with each iteration

Comment: I was thinking the same thing - however, `ActiveDocument.Tables.Count` doesn't actually increment.